# Host my own user authentication service on my own server?

Tags: postgresql, oauth, hosting

I have tried Google with queries similar to the title of this question, but haven't found anything useful.

**Background:** I am building a web app and would like to add a user authentication level to it. I cannot imagine anything worse than building a user authentication system from the ground up, so I want a quick solution.

**I'm looking for** open source software I can host on my server that provides an auth layer I can connect to, with multiple user accounts

**Criteria:**

- I want to host the software on my own server
- Provide a log in screen that works with multiple sign in strategies - twitter, facebook, vanilla email, etc.
- Persists users to a database (preferably **postgres**) and persists session data
- Preferably lets me store a minimal amount of data per user, like key value store
- Has a client-side (Javascript) API, like Facebook's JS, so I can use this auth service on multiple sites. Namely, I want to use it on localhost or my own file system (when allowing file cookies). Client side JS API exposes methods like log in / log out
- Has a server side API (such as exposes local RESTful endpoints) so that when I do build out my server side app for other data storage outside of the user, my app can query the auth service for log in status.
- I want to run this stack completely independently of my own app - in fact I want to run this auth service and purely communicate to it from my local dev environment without building any server side app of my own.

I have used Firebase and they do many of the things that I want, including log in strategies and the client / server side APIs, but I want to be able to host my own version of this.

I can't imagine anyone takes pleasure out of building user authentication of any kind, so I'm surprised I haven't found anything in research.

I also know this is an open-ended question, but as far as I can tell I haven't found **anything** satisfying my requirements.

Comment: I'm still figuring out [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/), but I think it hits some of your authentication questions, at least based on stuff I see in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/meanjs); I think RESTful endpoints are DIY though.

Comment: Check this matrix out. There are a couple of rows for authentication schemes, as well as a ton of other things. Again, maybe you don't want these frameworks, but it might be helpful: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r8rJy2Q5p5QORYKcye93UECwOlSgFL24c5fyF7dqhaM/edit#gid=1607194899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is something called a Single Sign On solution. According to [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations) there is nothing currently that meets my criteria.

Instead I have chosen to just run a local webserver and implement a regular auth flow.

Answer (score 1):

I like Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), which is for Rails. It has an active community with a boatloads of plugins available that can fulfill many of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a language specified; most languages and frameworks have their own implementations. Can you provide more information?

Example: I use the Flask framework on python. In addition, I use the Authomatic library which provides Oauth access for twitter, google, facebook, etc.